# Enabling desktop site in webview (android app)

Tags: android, webview

i want to display facebook like desktop site on my application i've tried using "facebook.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");" but it didn't work for me.
please help!!

```
public class FaceBookFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView facebook;

    public FaceBookFragment() {

    }

    @SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface" })
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);
        WebView facebook = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        facebook.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = facebook.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        facebook.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/login/");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: "i've tried using "facebook.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");" but it didn't work for me" -- when you tried a user agent string that identified a *desktop* Web browser, what were your results?

Comment: nothing happened result were same as before...